# continue count down after refresh

Tags: javascript, counter, countdown, countdowntimer

The counter works properly but starts again after refresh
How can I continue after refreshing the counter?

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
  
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  
        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  
        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  window.onload = function () {
    var duration = 60 * 2,
        display = document.getElementById("timer");
    startTimer(duration, display);
  };
```

Comment: Store the count in `localStorage` and upon page load, check to see if there is a count in there and if so, initialize the count to that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Was curious about this statement: "_How can I continue after refreshing the counter?_" - Don't know if OP meant page or not. Given the code above, the time restarts upon reaching zero.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the timer to start over counting down again?  If that is the case, 1. assign the output of `setInterval` to a variable; 2. In the `if` statement change `timer = duration;` to `clearInterval(variableNameSetBySetInterval)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try and use localStorage.
localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session end.
for example:

```
localStorage.setItem("duration",60);
localStorage.getItem("duration"); //60
```

check out this documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage